# What is the correct syntax to spawn a process in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, spawn

I'm trying to follow along with

http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options

In an effort to do

```
./node_modules/.bin/mocha --reporter json -u tdd
```

I have tried

```
var mocha    = spawn('./node_modules/.bin/mocha', ['--reporter json -u tdd']);
```

But I get the following error

```
error: unknown option `--reporter json -u tdd'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking quickly at the reference URL you provided, it seems that your bracketed arguments need to be separate:

```
var mocha    = spawn('./node_modules/.bin/mocha', ['--reporter','json','-u','tdd']);
```